# Angular2 - No provider for service found

Tags: exception, dependency-injection, angular

I have defined 3 components in my application. AppComponent, MainComponent and TextComponent.

AppComponent contains MainComponent as follows. Note that I have two services I have included in the providers attribute, CommonEventsService, CommonProductEventsService

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-main></my-main>
  `,
  providers: [CommonEventsService, CommonProductEventsService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, MainComponent]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {...}
```

Main component is included in the directives attribute in the AppComponent. The Main component is defined as follows:

```
@Component({
  template: "<my-add-text></my-add-text>",
  selector: "my-main",
  directives: [TextComponent]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {...}
```

Note that I have included the TextComponent in the directives attribute above. The TextComponent is defined as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-add-text",
  templateUrl: "/app/scripts/components/add/text.component.html",
})
export class TextComponent {
 constructor(private commonProductEvents: CommonProductEventsService){}
}
```

The problem is that when the application is loaded, I get the following error.

```
EXCEPTION: No provider for CommonProductEventsService! (TextComponent ->   CommonProductEventsService) in [addText in MainComponent@41:13]
```

But I have registered the CommonProductEventsService in the AppComponent. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce. See [Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jJbzVe?p=preview).

Do you have

```
CommonEventsService
CommonProductEventsService
```

in the same file as the components but further below in the file?

Then you either need to move them upwards, use `forwardRef` or move them into as separate file and import them.

See also
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Is there a limit to how many services can be declared in providers: [] array? I have 20 services declared in there and in the child components, it is throwing error.

Comment: I don't think there is a limit, at least not that small.

Comment: And does the order, in which the services are defined, matter? If they have dependencies on each other?

Comment: Yes, the order matters. Classes are not hoisted. If a class is used as Type that wasn't yet processed, it is unknown. The easiest way IMHO is to put every class in it's own file.

Comment: Hi  Günter Zöchbauer, I have a MainComponent and I've defined 20 services in the providers like this : providers:[CommonEventsService, CommonProductEventsService, ProductsService, FontsService, DesignColorsService,
                ClipartSvgsService, ClipartTagsService, DesignsService, OrdersService, PriceService, SignedUrlsService, S3ProcessorService,
                FontProcessorService, ProductsHelperService, DesignColorsProcessorService, SaveProcessorService, PriceProcessorService, 
                OrderHelperService, LoadOrderHelperService, CheckoutService, ShareHelperService]

Comment: But I get angular2.dev.js:23730 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for SaveProcessorService! (MainComponent -> PriceProcessorService -> SaveProcessorService)                                          ....  Any idea what could this be?

Comment: Is this `providers: [...]` on the root component?

Comment: it's in the MainComponent.  The root component loads the MainComponent through it's template : "<main></main>".                                    The root component and Main component are in different folders.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: No. Its company's code. I moved the providers in the root component and now I get different error. I get  EXCEPTION: No provider for OrderHelperService! (MainComponent -> OrderHelperService)... I've checked and the OrderHelperService is clearly defined in the roots providers.

Comment: For the Plunker the classes would only need the constructor with the parameter list, empty contructor body and also otherwise empty.